# Is there a way to select an input of the parent form as a child with id specified?

Tags: jquery

Hey guys, quick question,

I have an id that is applied multiple times on one of my pages (I used multiple duplicate ids because I also have a class applied that determines if the icon is a certain color rather than just duplicate the id css for each button color). I am using a jquery form handler that initiates on form submission and I would like to add an attribute to the submit button but since there is another button on the same page with the same id, I am having difficulty getting this to work. Is there a way to select an input by id of the parent form?

For example (I know it is wrong but it is what I want to achieve that matters in this example)

```
$("form#invite").submit(function() {


$(this).("#buttonid").attr({ disabled:true, value:"Sending..." });
```

Comment: An ID used more than once is invalid, you need to fix your HTML in this case.  You can use multiple classes on an element to do what you want...but don't re-use IDs, they're unique, and many things are optimized around them being unique...and things break when you break that rule.

Comment: You're going to run into problems with IE when using duplicate IDs. You can use multiple classes on an element so it doesn't matter if you're using a class already. You can have <div class="red icon-arrow big-text"> etc... Change your code before continuing, you're trying to get unexpected behavior to work. Not a good practice.

Comment: OMG Nick you ALWAYS beat me to it!

Comment: @Marko - Sorry :)  +1 for illustrating the multiple class syntax...I'm astonished how many web developers aren't aware of this.

Comment: lol I actually did not know you could use multiple classes, really appreciate that guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute [must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) in a HTML document.  Multiple elements with the same ID will cause you no end of grief, more-so in some browsers than in others.

To answer your question, you can use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or selector context:

```
// Selector context, supplying the current element as the second argument:
$("#buttonid", this).attr({ disabled:true, value:"Sending..." });

// find()
$(this).find("#buttonid").attr({ disabled:true, value:"Sending..." });
```

Comment: This *shouldn't* work, because it'll just optimize it to `document.getElementById('buttonid')`...jQuery assumes IDs are unique.

Comment: @Nick: I didn't notice the multiple id thing until after - I ashamedly skim-read the question (it's late).  I think the result varies per browser - I thought `querySelectorAll()` was given priority if available?

Comment: I just modified the css, you are correct in suggesting to keep ids unique, but this suggestion is still useful for future reference in similar situations. Thanks Andy.

Comment: @Andy - Sometimes...but in this case jQuery will ignore everything and shoot for `getElementById()`, it does this if it detects a `#id` pattern, check it out here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L120

Comment: @Nick: [it does work](http://www.jsfiddle.net/tMdtK/), tested in IE, Fx and Chrome.  Looks like jQuery/Sizzle is smart enough to account for this with selector context/find. Of course, I don't advocate dupe ids in the slightest :-)

Comment: @Andy - You're right, Sizzle has a work around for this internally, really slowing down the ID selector along the way as well...I guess John guessed if you're using a context with an ID selector, something was up and it attempts to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

`$("form#invite").find("#buttonid").attr({ disabled:true, value:"Sending..." });`

Comment: I appreciate your time Sinan, but this actually did not work. I ended up just modifying the css of my document as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You should really try to find a way to keep the id's unique. Like using a classname or not naming them at all. In any case, here is the answer to you question:

```
$("form#invite").submit(function() {
    $(this).find("#buttonid").attr({ disabled:true, value:"Sending..." });
}
```